# Heroku deploy successful but i get application error

Tags: python, heroku

So I tried hosting a discord bot with Heroku and a GitHub repository. The deploy was a success but when I went to the app it gave me an error. It told me to check my logs and it says this:

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
-----> Using buildpack: heroku/python
-----> Python app detected
-----> No Python version was specified. Using the buildpack default: python-3.9.5
       To use a different version, see: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes
-----> Installing python-3.9.5
-----> Installing pip 20.2.4, setuptools 47.1.1 and wheel 0.36.2
-----> Installing SQLite3
-----> Installing requirements with pip
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types -> (none)
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 51.3M
-----> Launching...
       Released v3
       https://commanderzavala.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

The code I wrote is in python and the requirements.txt is empty. I used `replit` to write the code if that matters.

You can find the code here: https://github.com/MacatacWarrior/commanderzavala

Comment: What does it mean you went to the app? The app is a `worker` so there is no web frontend and accessing the homepage gives an error (as expected). The workers are background thread, try to add some logging to follow what happens after deployment

Comment: @BeppeC the build log is the only log i have access to (not allowed to install stuff, wont go more into it). I dont know how else to do get access to those logs.

Comment: Look in the Dashboard: More -> View Logs (ie https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/{app_name}/logs

Comment: Ok, so the error was H14 which says it doesn't have any web dynos. So I need to add a web dyno to the Procfile, I know to format it as web:<command>. What do I put as the command?

Comment: To run a Discord bot you dont need a web dyno, the bot runs as background thread. If you want to access it via the web you can use a web dyno (`web: app.py`) but you then need to build a web api/frontend (for example Flask)